# Function call faster than on the fly calculation?

Tags: optimization, lua, function-call

I am now seriously confused. I have a function creating a table with a random number of entries, and I tried two different methods to choose that number (which is somewhat wheighted):

Method 1, separated function

```
local function n()
    local n = math.random()
    if n < .7 then return 0
    elseif n < .8 then return 1
    end
    return 2
end

local function final()
    for i = 1, n() do
        ...
    end
end
```

Method 2, direct calculation

```
local function final()
    local n = math.random()
    if n < .7 then n = 0
    elseif n < .8 then n = 1
    else n = 2
    end
    for i = 1, n do
        ...
    end
end
```

The problem is: for some reason, the first method performs 30% faster than the second. Why is this?

Comment: Really? I'd say that method 1 would be slower because of repeated global access to the global `math`.

Comment: How did you measure it?

Comment: I would have voted for the second method as there is no overhead of function call

Comment: @Ihf the number of accesses to `math` is the same, one.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov `local t = os.clock() for i = 1, 1000 do final() end print((os.clock() - t) / 1000)`

Comment: Anyway the function `final` is part of a bigger method which performs some operations and loops based on the number decided here, yesterday I was trying calling the bigger method and measuring it. I can swear the first method took about 0.05 seconds every time I run it, while the second took 0.07. Trying only calling `final` today showed you guys are right, the second is faster.

Comment: It's doing it again! Crap. I think I'll rewrite it all, as it's also slower than my previous version of this thing.

Comment: if you are so desperately in need of performance you maybe should consider another language. :)

Comment: Are you sure your OS is not busy with something else while you are running this code?

Comment: @user6245072, that's a very crude benchmark. `os.clock` is not that precise and 1000 iterations is way too small for such a small function. You were mostly measuring random hiccups in your CPU.

Comment: @Piglet, Lua is pretty fast as it is and in JIT incarnation it is almost as fast as native code.

Comment: I am not really that disperate for performance, I'm just rewriting some modules for the game I'm writing and making them slower is just pointless.

Comment: It keeps happening even with the old module. The first method is faster. Could it be something related to branch prediction? I once read something about functions storing the result for a given input, so next time the function is called with the same input, it already knows the result, but I think it was about C++, also this function takes no input and I think the randomness excludes branch prediction, so... should I post the whole code?

Comment: if lua is fast enough for nginx and redis, it's fast enough for most purposes.. @Piglet

Comment: Whole code [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128854/unexpected-result-when-trying-to-optimize-code)

Answer (score 0):

No, call will never be faster than plainly inlining it. All the difference for the first method is adding extra work of setting up stack and dismantling it. The rest of code, both original and compiled is exactly the same, so it is only natural that "just calculation" will be faster than "just calculation + some extra work".

Your benchmark seem to be imprecise. For such a lightweight function a `for` loop and `os.clock` call themselves will take almost as many time as the function itself, so combined with `os.clock` inherent low resoulution and small amount of loops your data is not really statistically significant and you're mostly seeing results of random hiccups in your hardware. Use better timer and increase number of loops to at least 1000000.

Comment: Lol it's already long to wait 50 - 70 seconds for 1000 tests.

Comment: @user6245072, there's nothing in your code that would give such a delay. Except the `...` part you didn't post. Measure without it to see real difference.

Comment: The fact is, whitout it, the one-function-method is faster as expected. With it, the two-functions-method is faster. I posted the code [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128854/unexpected-result-when-trying-to-optimize-code)